# React - Typescript - narrow down callback type based on optional boolean prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `<Selector />` component which can accept an optional param `isMulti: boolean`.
It also have a required param **onSelected**, who's signature should be changed based on **isMulti** value (wheater is true or not - undefined)

I've created an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-lqfn88?file=components/Selector.tsx)

My typescript implementation fails somewhere in the following implementation (I think):

```
interface ISelectorProps<T> {
  isMulti?: T;
  onSelected: T extends true
    ? ((options: string[]) => void)
    : ((option: string) => void);
}
```

So the idea is that, if **isMulti** is provided, **onSelected** should return an array of strings, otherwise, it should provide only a string;

As you can see in the editor, TS complains here:

[image]

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & string[]'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

The signature of **onSelected** is wrongly typed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple thing to do is to define your type as either/or with the `isMulti` being the selector. This is called a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)

```
type ISelectorProps = {
  isMulti: true;
  onSelected: (options: string[]) => void;
} | {
  isMulti: false;
  onSelected: (option: string) => void;
}

function x(props: ISelectorProps) {
    if (props.isMulti === true) {
        props.onSelected(['hey', 'there']);
    } else {
        props.onSelected("only one");
    }
}
```

So here, when `isMulti` is true, you have `onSelected` taking an array, and a single string otherwise.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgyhANhAxsA9gJwAqfWAZygF4oBvAWACgooBLAgWQFdFg6AuKYTZiAbmq10AOwTI0EACZcAFPnaiCXAjzoiA5gG0AugEoSAPigA3dHSmCqAXygAfckPpNW7LgDMAhogICno8VRgaTkFOlEVNU0DYmMzCytramp3ZhE0cJEoAA9ZMDxCLngkIKxcfAIDShpaencoPIKCADoGFjY6Kqda2vyK5oCSySlZLQByAAsIEDGAGigx4CnMCDH9Kx7bJF9HGp7aPsIBsSHgkYAiUUQQKFEIc70N2qSbIA)

The TypeScript Playground should be correct, but I am finding that at least in a different environment, the `else` is not type narrowing correctly. I have found that changing the check to be exact, `if (props.isMulti === true)` then the compiler does resolve the `else` condition to narrow to `onSelected(option: string)` correctly. Not a perfect soliton, but could perhaps be done instead with an enum instead of boolean.

Comment: Or just specify optional params on the func itself? `onSelected: (options: string[] | string) => void;`

Comment: This helps the user of the function know which type of function to pass depending on the `isMulti`, so while that could work, it shifts some of the responsibility as well as feedback via the compiler.

Comment: @crashmstr I see that in your TS playground example it works, but in mine it doesn't.  Have a look again at the link above. I've updated the code as you said.

It still complains about the same error

Comment: oh, wait a bit, now I saw the difference, I do have to call props.onSelected ...I can't use destructuring anymore, that's a pitty, any other alternatives?

Comment: now it only complains when calling the method with a string props.onSelected('asda');

Comment: @BarbuBarbu I can see that in your case and testing in a different environment, that the compiler seems to think that if it is not `onSelected(x: string[])` it is `onSelected(x: string[] & string)`. There might be something with compiler settings, but this *should* work

Comment: @BarbuBarbu I've updated my answer, but if you change the check to be `props.isMulti === true`, it does work correctly. Probably something with compiler parameters.

Comment: ok, now this works, but it means I can't use destructuring... still a bit weirdo

Comment: @BarbuBarbu Destructuring could possibly work if you do it twice (e.g. in the if and the else). The problem is that when you destructure, you are disassociating the destructured `isMulti` from the props type related `onSelected`.

Comment: that's because discriminated unions does not handle destructuring... I guess

Comment: @BarbuBarbu Correct, because it is no longer a discriminated union once destructed.

Comment: well, then this solution comes with a downside.... but at least, it's working, I guess there's not other more elegant solution that this

Comment: @BarbuBarbu It looks like [TypeScript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#cfa-aliased-conditions) might have the ability to work with destructured properties. It just came out recently, so you might check it out.

Comment: @crashmstr I've just checked with **typescript 4.4.2** and still does not work. 
I get this  `const onSelected: (arg0: string[] & string) => void`

Comment: @crashmstr I've even checked their example, and it doesn't work, locally... but [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0lAvAWAFBW1APlAbygGsBLAOwBMAuKAIgGNSAnBgGwjoBopmFLSAVwDOtcoIC2AIwjMoAX0w48hEhRr1hAR0EJmnHsNKUIAGQjkA5sDhjJMufIDcmTADNB5BsFIB7clB6EAgAFMKIkLTwSBAAlHbSsoRKOAD0qVAAogAewHzeUL6CwFA20ADkZFTlUG6kEGyUtSzCwAB0KdgM-q2qVU3yqFDhMS4YnVCkblAh-agoKPRMrBx0sclYymkZAOrQxOS+AO5QR9CIAG7QCFDL7OeyEACEE8r6wILMAQCyCDZtAAUAJJQABUwwiEDafAEIjB4IATGNlIpNtgGsJoARXtsoHsSIcTmdyvooBw3CUjqQbIFhjoglA4I8Xmitu9PgERpA2kYTOYrDTQYjkThUfIgA) seems to be working, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @BarbuBarbu Likely something in the tsconfig file that affects the settings.

Comment: yes, it was due to VS code which was using an older version of TS